# Problems while reading value from app.config file

Tags: c#, windows-7, build, app-config, windows

I am making one windows application in c# in where i added one file as app.config file.I have written some code in that file as

```
    <appSettings>
       <add key ="FlagForArchiving" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
```

In 'program.cs' file i am reading this value as

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FlagForArchiving"].ToString();
```

On local machine i can retrieve value from config file but whenever i am building that application and running on any other machine then I cant read the value from config file.I am trying to run my application on windows 7.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue. But can you provide the complete exception details?

Comment: @Polity - he didn't say anything from a phone app

Comment: @Polity: The question in your link is specific to configuration on WP7 but OP's OS is Windows 7. Hence not a duplicate.

Comment: @masterchris_99 - oh my... where is my head :)

Comment: I am not making phone app.I am making c# windows app.My application name is OBViewer.and in current application there is app.config file.But whenever i am making build of that application,in that build there  are two files as OBViewer.exe.config and OBViewer.vshost.exe.config but there is no app.config file.I am confusing about that.please help me

Comment: Also which .NET framework are you using (because ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete and replaced by ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)? Which system (local or "any other machine") has Windows 7 (or is it both)? This question apparently needs elaboration!

Comment: @Dany: OBViewer.exe.config is actually your built app.config file.  OBViewer.vshost.exe.config is the file created by the IDE to assist debugging.

Comment: @Kash: I am using .net framework 3.5 but in that i am not getting ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. How to get it?PLease

Comment: @Dany Add reference to `System.Configuration`

Comment: @V4Vendetta : i added the System.Configuration but still i am not getting ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. Please can you tell me how to get it?

Comment: @Dany: In your project settings, what is "Target Framework" set to?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham : Target framework is .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: @Dany: This class exists since .Net 2.0, so that's probably not the problem anyhow.  Add the reference in your project to `System.Configuration`, then try: the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class.  You might be missing the `using System.Configuration;` directive at the top of your source code file...

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham : Ya i got ConfigurationManager.AppSettings but still i cant read value from config file

Comment: @Dany: Check out my answer.  If you copy over the right file it should work.  So far you haven't give any feedback that indicates that you copied over "OBViewer.exe.config" to the machines you're trying to run it on.  Do that and it should work.

Comment: @ Merlyn Morgan-Graham: I tried that but it doesn't work.My targeted framework is .Net Framework 3.5 and the machine on which i am trying to run that build have .net framework 4.0 client profile.Is there any problem?

Comment: @Dany: You might also want to use the auto-generated settings feature: Right click your project -> Properties -> Settings -> Generate settings file, edit the settings there (make them "Application" scope).  Access them through `Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName`.

Comment: @Dany: Were you able to resolve this issue (considering you have accepted the best answer)? If not, please post the complete exception details with stack trace.

Comment: Please consider taking extended discussions to [chat] rather than having them here in the comments.

Comment: @Dany: I believe you got a FileNotFoundException on the second machine. But I see that you have edited your question since to remove that. Are you seeing a different exception now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.config` is renamed to `<MyProgramName>.exe.config` when you build.  When your program runs it will look for that `<MyProgramName>.exe.config` file, not `app.config`.

You need to deploy the renamed file (`<MyProgramName>.exe.config`) along with your program.

In your case, you need to copy over `OBViewer.exe`, `OBViewer.exe.config`, and any other files that `OBViewer.exe` depends on (e.g. other .dll assemblies in your debug/release directory).

By the way, this renamed file is often commonly referred to as "app.config", even if it doesn't have the same filename.

Answer (score -1):

and the app.config file exists on the other machine?
Before reading check if it exists

The exception you get says whats incorrect: "FileNotFoundException"

**EDIT**
here is the correct way!

```
if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile))
{
    MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FlagForArchiving"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: -1 for `App.Config` will never exists on the machine. It is called `<ProgrammName>.exe.config`!

Comment: he called it app.config. thats why I used this string. If I use anything else I only would confuse him

Comment: @masterchris_99: that doesn't mean that you can't correct him. Instead you have given another inaccurate statement which actually adds to the confusion!

Comment: is it okay to access the value with a messagebox? Sorry I don't know what he do with the value. I hope it is not incorrect!

Comment: I wouldn't do things this way.  I'd just assume the app.config file exists, and let it bomb out if it doesn't.  The file should always exist...

Comment: i want that value for further processing.But i cant read from file. How to get these value?Please help me and thanks for response.

Comment: first you have to copy the correct app config file. with my code posted you ensure that you don't try to read from config file while it not exists. If it not exists you can add some stock config

Comment: @masterchris_99 : I also tried your code But still i cant get value from config file. And what is Stock config?Can you tell me please?\

Comment: I mean some default values. If you don't get some values the problem ist that there is no config file. Ensure that the config file exists. In the properties of the config file you can say that it has to be copied to the release folder

Comment: @masterchris_99: I have more values not only FlagForArchiving value.So i cant use Stock values