# How do you get an app.config value when not debugging?

Tags: c#

I have a console application that stores credentials in app.config. Everything works fine if I open the solution and press F5 to debug it. But if I double click on the executable directly it crashes (because it can't read the values).

The app.config file is very simple

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="username" value="foo" />
      <add key="password" value="bar" />
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

and read by

```
string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
```

But it never reads the values unless I am running the program through Visual Studio.

Comment: do you have an app.config in your built folder?

Comment: Your .config must have same name as your executable (and VS do that automagically); so "sample.exe" will get those values from "sample.exe.config"; can you confirm both files are in the same folder?

Comment: app.config needs to be at same place with .exe

Comment: It's a really bad idea to store passwords in a config..

Comment: Rubens, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems while reading value from app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163311/problems-while-reading-value-from-app-config-file)